# removing email accounts that have the same user name as mine

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

i have a hotmail account and have recently discovered that there is a Gmail account with the same name i use for my hotmail account? does this mean they have access to my hotmail/outlook/google/youtube/facebook accounts and if so how can i remove the gmail account as i have noticed unusal activity within my hotmail account, things deleted, emails not coming thru to my hotmail, its not right, ive changed my password a million times, removed devices associated with my google account, updated my backup recovery info, and put in 2step verification, but im always bypassed by code generator, and within facebook it keeps being reactivated, and will bypass a tx to my ph?

Please advise if anyone has any info much appreciated
Shannon

Please read below

Sorry Im just as confused too, but what im asking is, is it possible a gmail account using the same username as your hotmail email account and google account link up together in anyway because they share the same user name? where they are all accessible by logging into one of these accounts? As i know google has the ability to link/sync all your accounts together so you can access them on any device from anywhere?

I hope that is more understandable?.. 
Regards
Shan

Comment: Hotmail (Outlook.com) and Gmail are two completely separate services. Accounts on either are, by definition, not the same account. Nor is it the same as a Facebook account. Your question is otherwise quite difficult to understand. Can you please clarify exactly what you're trying to solve? (Don't respond in the comments; [edit] your question.)

Comment: Unless the websites have explicitly configured to function that way, user accounts across services are not linked.  In regards to the send as functionality that gmail has, the gmail user would need your hotmail username and password in order to link the accounts.

Comment: Yes ok so iit is possible because, emails arent coming thru, deleted emails that i havent read etc.etc. Ok well I believe she does, so how can i unlink these 2 accounts without having her mobile with me?

Answer (score 1):

Unless **you** have linked the accounts, this is not possible. There are many people with the same user name but since you are on different services (hotmail and gmail) they do not conflict. Just be sure when you tell people your email address you specify '@gmail.com'.

Google cannot "link/sync all your accounts together so you can access them on any device from anywhere". Android has that functionality but only if you log into each individual account with your username and password.